# How to stop repeating a code block that returns pricing info?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have to return pricing data. Rather than re-typing the same calculation, I would like to reference a single code block that will compute the answer.

I have to say that I'm lost. I mean, I'm working through it, but I'm not even sure what to google.
What I have below is where I am, and I'm hoping someone can provide at least some guidance or direction. Like even "google this" would be helpful.

So I have a controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RetailTimePriceDisplay(string zero)
{
    var j = await PriceCalculator(zero); //zero is job file ID
    ViewBag.priceTrk = j.priceTrk;
    ViewBag.priceVan = j.priceVan; //Send these viewbag prices to the view for user.
    ViewBag.rateTravelDrvr = j.rateTravelDrvr;

    return View();
}
```

So I'd like to reference a different code block, called "PriceCalculator". This is the code block I would like to stop re-typing everywhere that I need it to be.

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<PricingIndex> PriceCalculator(string zero)
{
    //call route info
        var i = await BingMapRouteCalculate(zero);
        //call pricing index
        PricingIndex u = new PricingIndex();
        var j = new PricingIndex();

    //access job file [zero]
    u.rateMile = _context.ProductList.First(n => n.AccountNumber == 4202).ListPrice;
    decimal rateLabor = _context.ProductList.First(n => n.AccountNumber == 4201).ListPrice;
    //calculate 'TRK' price using BingMaps
    u.priceTrk = (i.TravelDistance * u.rateMile) + 100; 
    //calculate 'VAN' price using BingMaps
    u.priceVan = i.TravelDistance * u.rateMile; 

    //calculate 'rateTravelDrvr' using BingMaps     
    decimal rateTravelDrvr = Math.Ceiling(i.TravelDuration * rateLabor);

    return u;

}
```

I am currently getting an error at "return u;" of Cannot return a value from an iterator. Which I am researching.

And then I was trying to access this object. I did this because it seemed like I had to create a model of sorts to contain/structure the data produced from "PriceCalculator" before passing it to the starting controller.

```
public class PricingIndex
    {

        public decimal rateMile { get; set; }
        public decimal priceVan { get; set; }
        public decimal priceTrk { get; set; }
        public decimal rateTravelDrvr { get; set; }
            
    }
```

So, yeah, I'm kind of throwing things on the wall to see what sticks, which is extremely frustrating. What you see here is where I am at currently. I'm not sure how to title this question.

Any direction would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You use yield return or just return another IEnumerable inside a method that declares the return type is IEnumerable. However, your controller code doesn't indicate you need an  IEnumerable

Comment: @Martheen Do I need to change this: public async IAsyncEnumerable<PricingIndex>?

Comment: Yep, just return PricingIndex

Comment: @Martheen public async PricingIndex Price(string zero) gives error : The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or IAsyncEnumerator<T> .

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async please read the documentation before using them

Comment: @Martheen THIS WAS HELPFUL. I could give you credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this might have gotten answered in the comments but was the solution changing it from `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` to `Task<T>` so the return type is an object of type T rather than an enumerable of objects of type T?

```
public async Task<PricingIndex> PriceCalculator(string zero)
{
   // Your pricing calculator code goes here.
}
```

Comment: This was a while ago, but yes,